# How to break the crawl when it is on the last page (requests, python)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I made a crawl program with requests and I would like to stop it when it is on the last page. Where should I put the break statement to break the loop on the last page? Now it runs but it doesn't stop on the last page. I attached the program. I will appreciate any help.

```html
import requests
from lxml import html
from time import sleep
import csv

headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
}

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://95.167.116.116:8080',
    'https': 'http://88.157.149.250:8080',
}
page_counter = 1
links = []
while True:
        try:
            url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_{0}?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A3375251%2Cn%3A%213375301%2Cn%3A10971181011%2Cn%3A11444071011%2Cp_8%3A2229059011%2Cn%3A11444072011%2Cn%3A11444086011%2Cn%3A2632268011&page={0}&bbn=11444086011&ie=UTF8&qid=1517650207".format(
                page_counter)
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, stream=True)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                source = html.fromstring(response.content)
                links.extend(source.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"result")]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/@href'))
                page_counter += 1
            else:
                break
        except:
            print("Connection refused by the server..")
            print("Let me sleep for 5 seconds")
            print("ZZzzzz...")
            sleep(5)
            print("Current page ", page_counter)
            print("Was a nice sleep, now let me continue...")

csvfile = "products.csv"

# Assuming res is a flat list
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in links:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

Comment: What should be the last page you want to visit? For me it doesn't matter how huge is the value of `page_counter `, I'll get the first page as a response from the site. In my opinion you should crawl the next page url from the site and follow it, that's much more stable.

Comment: On this link there are 44 pages but I would like this program with other links for subcategories with 1000 pages. So this subcategory has 44 pages. Can you edit the program to see please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet as an example, and then please extend it with your custom functions:

```
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from lxml import html

headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
}

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://95.167.116.116:8080',
    'https': 'http://88.157.149.250:8080',
}

links = []
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A3375251%2Cn%3A%213375301%2Cn%3A10971181011%2Cn%3A11444071011%2Cp_8%3A2229059011%2Cn%3A11444072011%2Cn%3A11444086011%2Cn%3A2632268011&bbn=11444086011&ie=UTF8&qid=1517831374'

while True:
    try:
        print('Fetching url [%s]...' % url)
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            source = html.fromstring(response.content)
            links.extend(source.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"result")]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/@href'))
            try:
                next_url = source.xpath('//*[@id="pagnNextLink"]/@href')[0]
                url = urljoin('https://www.amazon.com', next_url)
            except IndexError:
                break
    except Exception:
        print("Connection refused by the server..")
        print("Let me sleep for 5 seconds")
        print("ZZzzzz...")
        sleep(5)
        print("Was a nice sleep, now let me continue...")

print(links)
```

Actually it scrapes the current page for the link of the next page. If the url of the next page can be found, then follows. If cannot be found, then breaks the `while` loop, and prints the collected `links` list.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way I would highly recommend using a framework like `Scrapy` for tasks similar to this. Batteries included and makes you suffer less. Much less.